# How to filter the Windows Security event log by SID?

Tags: powershell, windows-event-log, powershell-v3.0

I want to filter the event log for a certain user, but I don't think there's an option to search by SAMID.  There is a filter by `UserId` though, according to [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/01/24/use-powershell-cmdlet-to-filter-event-log-for-easy-parsing.aspx).  Is the following correct syntax correct to search the user in the screen shot below?

```
$events = get-winevent -filterhashtable 
  @{ logname='security'; path="Archive-Security-2015-04-14-02-13-02-299.evtx";
  UserId='S-1-5-21-220523388-838170752-839522115-yyyy' }
```

[image: Events]

I get "No events were found that match the specified selection criteria." with the above command.  But if I remove the `UserId` key, a long list is returned, so there should be nothing wrong with `logname` or `path`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought the `id` paramater under the hashtable filter is actually the `event id`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.  I pasted the command from a wrong attempt.  I have updated the question.  I used `UserId`='....'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `-FilterXPath` option instead!

In the following example, I've saved all events from the Security log on my machine to `seclog.evtx` on the Desktop and search for events with SubjectUserSid `S-1-5-18` (`LOCAL SYSTEM`):

```
$events = Get-WinEvent -Path "$HOME\Desktop\seclog.evtx" -FilterXPath '*[EventData[Data[@Name="SubjectUserSid"] = "S-1-5-18"]]'
```

In a script, I would probably opt for a [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) table to make the statement a bit more readable (here limited to the last 10 events):

```
$seclogSplat = @{
    'Path'        = "$HOME\Desktop\seclog.evtx"
    'FilterXPath' = '*[EventData[Data[@Name="SubjectUserSid"] = "S-1-5-18"]]'
    'MaxEvents'   = 10
}
$events = Get-WinEvent @seclogSplat
```

You can specify multiple non-exclusive criteria with `or`:

```
*[EventData[Data[@Name="SubjectUserSid"] = "S-1-5-18" or Data[@Name="SubjectUserSid"] = "S-1-0-0"]]
```

Comment: Thanks.  How do I specify a saved log file and the logname with the FilterXPath option?

Comment: @OldGeezer Sorry, didn't notice it was a Saved log file. Just use the `-Path` parameter, answer updated

Comment: Thanks. It works. One more question if you don't mind: what's the syntax for logical OR in that *[.[ [..]..].] thingy?

Comment: `or` (lowercase)

Comment: I found out that with this method I could also filter by SubjectserName, which is more user friendly than the SID.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any built in way to find out if a specific UserID exists.
However, you can just match the content of the message to find your SiD, as it should be unique:

> $events = get-winevent -logname security -path
>   "Archive-Security-2015-04-14-02-13-02-299.evtx" | where {$_.message
>   -match 'S-1-5-21-220523388-838170752-839522115-yyyy'}

There are also some [cleaner ways](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/06/04/data-mine-the-windows-event-log-by-using-powershell-and-xml.aspx) using XML filtering.
But personally I haven't had a need for them yet, and content matching the message has been sufficient so far.

Comment: That's what I did for further post processing to get my report.  But I prefer filtering before piping, as, as your linked article says, it's a greater than 100X difference in performance.  The said id exists, as the GUI event viewer shows.  What I am uncertain is the syntax or whether UserId key refers to this SID field.